# What is the best way to update database on 00:00 everyday in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, schedule

In an ASP.NET MVC4 project, I want to update some data in sql server(2012) on 00:00 everyday.
Maybe I have three choice:
1. writing an windows service which running on the server and execute database updating.
2. writing an sql server Stored Procedure which execute on 00:00 everyday.
3. use Third-party tools，like Quartz.Net, fluent.

Which one is the best choice? Why?

Comment: Do you have shell (RDP or Telnet) access to the server? If so, use Scheduled Tasks (using RDP) or the `at` command from Telnet.

Comment: Or if you're strictly running only SQL against a database, use SQL Server Agent instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comfortable with T-SQL and the task can be completely entirely within the database, then it makes sense to implement it as a stored proc and schedule it using SQL Server Agent. This reduces the number of external dependencies as everything happens inside SQL Server and there are less points of failure (e.g. it will still run if IIS or your web solution is down).

If your update needs to interact with other resources, such as importing a text file from a known location, etc., then you might also consider implementing it in SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services). This has the advantage of still being SQL hosted, while giving you access to additional functionality not easily achieved with a stored proc.

I would only implement as a batch process in .NET if I felt that the functionality required would be difficult or awkward to implement in a proc or SSIS package. This is especially relevant since SQL Server 2012 allows you to build an SSIS package using .NET type code, but it "lives" in the SSIS package that is registered on the SQL Server.

I wouldn't implement it within your ASP.NET solution at all unless it actually needs a web based user interface for some reason. The fact that you want to execute this process at precisely the same time every night tells me that this does not require human interaction.

Where a process can be fully automated, avoid putting a user interface or anything which can potentially hang or become a single point of failure while waiting for some kind of UI input. Remember, a presentation layer is for human interaction - consider if you need one. Better to implement it as a batch of some sort, which also makes it easier to execute via automation. There are exceptions to this rule, e.g. if you wanted to implement your update as a web API with a REST interface or the like, but as a general rule it holds true.

As a side note, if your aim is to run your process overnight, consider scheduling it in the early hours of the morning (between 3 and 4 am) rather than midnight as this is generally when most people are asleep and your update is least likely to impact the availability of your app and its database, or if your update is long running, run into an edge case like a daylight savings change or conflict with other overnight processes.

Comment: Hello, now I choose the resolution of SQL Stored Procedure.And I also use the windows azure cloud service.How can I use "Sql Server Agent" scheduler in azure to run my tasks. Looking forward to your answer! Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used the Azure service, so someone else may be better able to advise you on that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Hangfire.  Scheduled tasks in ASP.NET.  Super easy and reliable.

http://hangfire.io/

We just started using it and I like it.

Comment: I am sorry to ask what the difference between hangfire and Quartz.Net

Comment: I haven't used Quartz.Net so I can't comment intelligently.  I can say that hangfire was built specifically for ASP.NET and can handle app pool recycling and the other nuances of running in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I used all three ways you write, all have their pros and cons. But I suggest you to use Quartz.Net. It is very easy to impliment and very easy to use.
You can see [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net) a wonderful article by mike on Scheduled tasks in ASP.NET

Comment: how about the success rate of this method? I am afraid this method is not stable enough than stored procedure.What is your opinion about this issue?

Comment: I used this method several times and not face any issue, store procedure is also good but i will go for quartz.net